# Why do objects not get added to my array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, instance-variables, appdelegate

I have two custom classes: `FSGame` and `FSEvent`. `FSGame` has an ivar that should be an `NSMutableArray` of `FSEvent` objects.

Here's FSGame.h:

```
@interface FSGame : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *players;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *startTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *endTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *gameEvents;

@end
```

And here's my FSEvent.h:

```
@interface FSEvent : NSObject

@property NSInteger ID;
@property NSInteger pointTo;

@end
```

I use

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FSGame *game;
```

to keep an instance of `FSGame` in my `AppDelegate`. Then, in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I create an instance of `FSGame` so it can be filled throughout the "game".

```
_game = [[FSGame alloc] init];
```

Then, in one of my view controllers, I `alloc` and `init` an instance of `FSEvent` and then attempt to add it to the `.gameEvents` array:

```
[appDelegate.game.gameEvents addObject: event];
```

But something seems to go wrong here because if, from another view controller, I try to get access to that object, it will be `nil`:

```
FSEvent *previousEvent = [appDelegate.game.gameEvents lastObject];

if (previousEvent == nil) {
    NSLog(@"previousEvent is NIL!");
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked that `appDelegate.game.gameEvents` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the arrays, this does NOT happen when you use

> _game = [[FSGame alloc] init];

Try using a lazy instantiation in your FSGame class, add this code

```
-(NSMutableArray *)gameEvents{
    if(!_gameEvents){
        _gameEvents = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _gameEvents;
}
```

And that should be enough, also make sure of accesing by self.gameEvents and not by _gameEvents!

Comment: Thanks, thad solved my problem!

Why should I use self.gameEvents instead of _gameEvents, though?

Comment: When you use self.gameEvents you are using the getter, the one that makes sure that _gameEvents is not nil, if you use _gameEvents, you are accessing directly the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say with the code that's been shown, but it's possible that you never *create* the mutable array `gameEvents` and it's `nil` when you try to access it or add events to it. Make sure you're creating it somewhere, probably in `FSGame`'s `-init`:

```
_gameEvents = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed!

Answer (score 1):

_game.gameEvents is a pointer to a mutable array. It is not initialized, so its value is nil. There are no any mutable array to add objects to.

You can create it when needed writing this method in FSGame.m:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) gameEvents {
    if ( ! _gameEvents ) {
        _gameEvents = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _gameEvents ;
}
```